# Closure of a solid triangle in $\mathbb{R}_{(-)} \times \mathbb{R}_{\textit{finite complement}}$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Consider the product topology $\mathbb{R}_{(-)} \times \mathbb{R}_{\textit{finite complement}}$. What is the closure of a solid triangle in this space?

I know that if we consider the topological basis, we have $\mathcal{B_1} = \{(a,b):a<b\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2 = \{\mathbb{R}-F:F \text{ is finite}\}$ so I think I have an idea of what an open set in the space looks like, but how do I proceed with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $a\in\Bbb R$, and the vertical line $x=a$ intersects the solid triangle in infinitely many points, the whole vertical line is in the closure of the triangle. (Why? What does a basic open nbhd of a point on that line look like?)

Comment: I'm actually still confused. So we have the basis of the new space $\mathcal{B} = \{(m,n) \times (\mathbb{R}-F):m<n \text{ and } F \text{ finite }\}$ then if we consider the basic open neighborhood of $(a, y_0)$ then that's the set $\{(m,n) \times (\mathbb{R}-F)\}$ such that $m<a<n$ and $y \notin F$? How does this help?

Comment: @sedrick: If the line $x=a$ contains infinitely many points of the triangle, the set $\{a\}\times(\Bbb R\setminus F)$ must intersect the triangle, because $F$ is only finite. And that means that $(m,n)\times(\Bbb R\setminus F)$ must intersect the triangle. If $p$ is a point on that vertical line, every basic open nbhd of $p$ intersects the triangle, and $p$ is therefore in the closure of the triangle. (I have to go offline now, but I'll check back in the morning.)

Comment: thanks, I think I get it. Just another clarification: what if $x=a$ intersects the triangle only at one point? Doesn't this also count because a neighborhood of that point on the line will surely have a nonempty intersection with the solid triangle?

Comment: @sedrick: Yes, but it takes a little work to show it. The reason is that even if $\langle a,b\rangle$ is the only point of the triangle on the line $x=a$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $c\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon$ such that the line $x=c$ intersects the triangle in infinitely many points. Thus, any basic open nbhd $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\times(\Bbb R\setminus F)$ of $\langle a,b\rangle$ will contain points of the triangle lying on $x=c$.